# Is there an option to have score of UAC prompt?

Tags: batch-file, uac

I have this script that have goto getPrivileges, and this is useless coz it spams the whole time for UAC, Is there an option to make if you accepted UAC then does 1 thing and if you don't then another?

```
@echo off
:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
goto getPrivileges
exit /B
```

I would want to have something like this.

```
if %UACError% == 0 echo You clicked yes on UAC!
if %UACError% == 1 echo You clicked no on UAC!
```

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you have not specifically defined an issue with the submitted code, and sufficient information for us to all reproduce it, we are not here to provide free code or modifications.  If you have some code which you've found elsewhere, and it does not do what you need it to do, then it is your responsibility to modify it, not ours. The intention of this site is that we help you with a reproducible issue with your actual code, not with its functionality. Please make sure that you take the [tour], then read through all of [ask], to better understand how things work here.

Comment: but this code works, i only need one function for what you clicked in uac

Comment: We only help you to fix non working code, what you are looking for is somebody to write code for you, and that is not what we do on this site! _Oh and whilst that code may work for you, I would never use it…_

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing `goto getPrivileges` after the launching of the vbs script.

As far as I understand, the content of the vbs script is just relaunching the current batch (`!batchPath!`) with elevated privileges.

So this relaunching will do `:checkPrivileges` and go to `:gotPrivileges` if the elevation was successful, and execute your task requiring elevation.

So for me, you can get rid of your last `goto getPrivileges` that generates an infinite loop.

To avoid this infinite loop, you can also wait for the vbs script to terminate like this:

```
start /WAIT "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
```

Concerning the result of the UAC, I think the code part inside `:checkPrivileges` is meant to test just that.

If this does not work, I found another way to check the privileges ([here](http://www.blog4me.fr/article31/executer-un-script-batch-en-modifiant-le-niveau-du-controle-de-compte-dutilisateur), in french) :

```
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' ( ...privilege...   ) else (  ...no privilege... )
```

I didn't test it myself, though.